# C++14: How to design setters?

Tags: c++14, move-semantics, c++98

Let's say I have a rather large class `A` where there is a member of another class `B`:

```
class A {
    various large data members here
}


class B {
    public:
      setA( .... );
    private:
       A a;
}
```

What's the best (both in terms of speed but also code cleanliness) to write the setter for the `A`member in `B`?

First option would be typical C++98 style:

```
void setA(const A& a) { this.a = a; }
```

and using it like

```
B b;
A a;
b.setA(a);
```

This needs at least one copy, which could be costly. More efficient for large objects would probably a pointer:

```
class B {
    public:
      setA( .... );
    private:
       A *a;
}

setA(A *a) { this->a = a; }
```

and

```
B b;
A *a = new A();
b.setA(a);
```

This comes with all the nastiness of pointers, having to write custom destructors etc. In C++14 one could use std::uniuqe_ptr, but still this is way less cleaner than simply having a non-pointer member of `A` in `B`.

In C++14 there might be the option of using `rvalues` and move semantics with simple call by value, i.e.

```
void setA(A a) { this.a = std::move(a); }
```

and calling it like this:

```
B b;
A a;
b.setA(std::move(a));  // if we don't need a anymore
```

This is nice and clean and should be fast, but:

- I have to implement move semantics for class A. That's annyoing
- If I rely on automatically generated move semantics, it seems it is non-trivial (if possible at all) to check wether the object was moved or not: To check wether the move or copy constructor was called, I have to implement the copy constructor. Then move constructor and assignment will not be generated according to C++14 specs. If I do fancy things like setting the copy constructor to delete, my code won't compile (because some code parts explicitly require the `A` to be copied).

Herb Sutter arguments in his slides on *Back to the Basics! Essentials of Modern C++ Style* that you should usually prefer

```
void setA(const A& a) { this.a = a; }
```

but he talks in his presentation about a rather small member (a string), so for larger, more complex objects, this might not apply...

What is the proper way of doing it (In Java, this so easy...)

Comment: If you consider a setter that accepts and stores a pointer to an object as well as a setter that accepts an object by value or reference and stores a copy of the parameter, this is no decision about setter design, but about acquaintance vs. aggregation. This decision should be made first, then proceed to how to pass parameters.

Comment: I would very much prefer to call by value or reference and have copies _in general_ - this makes managing object lifetime much easier. Sometimes however you create a new object explicitly to set it as a new member. Then I want to prevent unnecessary copying due to the overhead. 
Thus all in all I want to avoid the pointers, which still leaves open the cost of passing by const ref vs move semantics.

Comment: i.e. I think I do not fully understand your remark. In all the examples, class B should own it's member and be responsible for it's lifetime. The only question is how to write clean functions yet avoid the hassle of unneccessary copies...

Comment: Your object should be ready to use after construction. Why don't pass class A during the construction of class B?

Comment: One sensible strategy of dealing with setters is avoiding them completely.

Comment: "In Java, this so easy" That's because Java hides pointers from you. Or rather, Java avoids uttering the word "pointer" while enforcing pointer semantics for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object should be ready to use after construction. Why don't pass class A during the construction of class B?

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : a{ a } {}
private:
    int a;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(int b, A a) : b{ b }, a{ std::make_unique<A>(a) } {}
private:
    int b;
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};

int main()
{
    B b(int{ 4 }, A{ 1 });
}
```

Comment: A is created during construction, but may need to be updated later on. Think e.g. of a tree struture, where you want to change properties of the nodes.

Comment: I see. You can update `A` from `B` in the above code. You can make member functions in `B` to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two setters, one for rvalue refferences, the other for const&, like this:

```
void setA(const A& a) { a_ = a; } 
void setA(A&& a) { a_ = std::move(a); }
```

Or, if you don't intend to use setA with any other types you could use universal refference:

```
template<typename T>
void setA(T&& a_) { a_ = std::forward<T>(a); }
```

But since you already allow setting the value, you might as well consider making it public, so that you don't have to worry at all about the setters.